# One of my classes is not returning to the main class after it completes. How do I get it to return?

Tags: java, methods, return

My main method is a switch case menu, that is working fine. If user selects 2, it goes to that class and returns normally but if user selects 1, it executes that method but then stalls and doesn't return. What am I missing? If I do a system exit it exits but I need it to return to the menu.

End of Method that stalls:

```
for (int index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
            System.setOut(console);
            System.out.printf("%-16s %16d %16d %16d %16s \n", items[index], supplyOnHand[index], last24HourUsage[index], daysOnHand[index], status[index]);
            System.setOut(o);
            System.out.printf("%-16s %16d %16d %16d %16s \n", items[index], supplyOnHand[index], last24HourUsage[index], daysOnHand[index], status[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        boolean exit = false;
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter your choice:");
            System.out.println("1. Enter new data.");
            System.out.println("2. Review latest data.");
            System.out.println("3. Exit.");
            Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice = sc1.nextInt();
            switch (choice){
                case 1:
                    Dashboard.main();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ReadFile.main();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    exit = true;
                    break;
            }
        } while (!exit);
    }
}
```

Editing to hopefully make it more clear. I am not skilled at the wording.
If I select 2 it executes and returns to the menu:

```
Please enter your choice:
1. Enter new data.
2. Review latest data.
3. Exit.
2
Please enter your choice:
1. Enter new data.
2. Review latest data.
3. Exit.
```

If I select 1 it doesn't return just hangs:

```
Please enter your choice:
1. Enter new data.
2. Review latest data.
3. Exit.
1

Welcome to the Rationed Medical Supply Dashboard.
After your entries of stock on hand and daily usage,
your days on hand and supply status will be displayed for each item.
The results will be displayed in the log below and
also in a running log in the file DashboardLog.txt
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
How many items are we tracking today?
1
Enter name of item # 1: 
1
How many of item # 1 do we have?: 
1
What was the usage of item # 1 in the last 24 hours: 
1
12/07/20 12:47:37
Current status of all items being tracked:
Item|             Supply on hand| Last 24 Hr Usage|    Days on hand|          Status|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1                               1                1                1         Critical
```

Comment: What do you mean by "returns normally" and "doesn't return" ? Do you have any exception during execution ?

Comment: Edited to try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

> One of my classes is not returning to the main class after it completes. How do I get it to return?

That's not how java works.

Methods run. Methods return. Classes are just bags of properties; some fields, some methods. They don't run. They do not return.

You're messing with System.out and then asking about 'stalling'. That's a bad plan, don't mess with setOut.

It's not stalling at all, at least, nothing in your paste suggests this. However, you are making `System.out` be something else, so, most likely, your code is not stalling, but e.g. `System.out.println("Please enter your choice:");` is being sent to something you can't see.

`System.setOut` changes `System.out` *everywhere*.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I just had to end on:

```
            System.setOut(console);
            System.out.printf("%-16s %16d %16d %16d %16s \n", items[index], supplyOnHand[index], last24HourUsage[index], daysOnHand[index], status[index]);
```

Instead of:

```
            System.setOut(o);
            System.out.printf("%-16s %16d %16d %16d %16s \n", items[index], supplyOnHand[index], last24HourUsage[index], daysOnHand[index], status[index]);
```

Works great now. Thanks for all the help!